# Doesn't print out to file using fprintf with fork()

Tags: fork, printf

So I've got a problem with my code and it's driving me nuts since I can't seem to figure out what's causing this. Basically, I'm trying to write to a file that I have open, using multiple child processes with fork(). Before I start forking, I can write to it just fine, but once I fork and THEN do an if statement to see if it's the child process, it won't write.

Basically, what I have is this:

```
FILE *output = NULL;
output = fopen(...); // Done successfully
fprintf(output, "This writes okay\n");
// Fork n processes
for (i = 0; i <= n; n++)
{
    pid[i] = fork();
    fprintf(output, "We can still write\n");
    if (pid[i] == 0) // Child process
    {
        fprintf(output, "This won't write to output\n");
        printf("I can still write and calculate stuff otherwise\n");
        ...
    }
}
```

Can anyone figure out why it's not able to write after checking to see if it's a child process? There's definitely no error with forking from what I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a file descriptor and using it in more than one process (for example in both a parent and child process) is a [race condition](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/POS38-C.+Beware+of+race+conditions+when+using+fork+and+file+descriptors) and will most likely cause problems and unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Well, crap. I forgot about race conditions. What workaround do you suggest for this then? If it helps, what I'm trying to do is compute something, write that to a file, and repeat this n times, using forks.

Comment: @LOL.NO. The workaround the link suggests is to close and reopen the file in the parent after forking (or just open it after forking so it's not inherited at all), but it depends on how you want to use the file (random access/appending writes etc)

Comment: Thank you--that helped quite a bit!